# Folland 2.34 exercise involving dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a question regarding the final step in my proof of the following exercise:

> **Exercise 2.34** Suppose $|f_n|\leq g \in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure. Show $\int f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n$.

Since $f_n\to f$ in measure, there exists a subsequence ${f_{n_j}}$ such that $f_{n_j}\to f$ a.e.. Now since $\forall j\in \mathbb{N}$ $|f_{n_j}|<g$ by the dominated convergence theorem we have that

$$\int f = \int \lim_{j\to\infty}f_{n_j}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\int f_{n_j}$$

Now all I need to do is show that $\lim_{j\to\infty}\int f_{n_j}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_{n}$ however I cannot see why this is true.

What is the reasoning which allows those two limits to be the same?

Comment: When you say converges in measure, do you mean local or global convergence in measure?

Comment: @MarkSaving The definition of "converges in measure" given by Folland is for every $\epsilon >0$ $\mu(\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ which I believe is local convergence in measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general fact (at least in, say, metric spaces): If you have a sequence $(f_n)$ and $f$ such that every subsequence has a further subsequence $(f_{n_{j_k}})$ converging to $f$, then the original sequence converges to $f$. This is just the negation of convergence (once you unpack the definitions).  The key is that the limit is the same no matter the subsequence.

In your case, you have a sequence of real numbers $\left(\int f_n\right)_n$.

Comment: A sequence with a convergent subsequence doesn't necessarily have a limit. It's only if it does have a limit that you can make such a claim.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I'm not claiming that; I'm assuming that *every* subsequence has a further convergent subsequence, and that the limit is independent of which subsequence you pick.

Comment: as a side note for OP: your argument can be reworded slightly to show that the sequence of real numbers $a_n:=\|f_n-f\|_{L^1}$ is such that every subsequence has a further subsequence which converges to $0$. Thus, by the lemma mentioned here, $a_n\to 0$, i.e $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a text which has this theorem? It didn't click that this was true before seeing this here.

Comment: For the case of real numbers I think Bartle's "Introduction to real analysis" has it. I'd be surprised if baby Rudin didn't. I'm pretty sure it'd be stated as an exercise though, in both of those.